# Populating NSOutlineView from dynamic dictionary

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdictionary, populate, nsoutlineview

in my app I have an NSOutlineView which should present data from an NSDictionary. This dictionary is fetched from a server and can be very different each time fetched.
It usually has a lot of sub objects such as other dictionaries and arrays which themselves too often contain other dictionaries and arrays.

I know how to populate a NSOutlineView when the data is static but I'm having huge difficulties coding it for dynamic data.

Also setting the name for column cells is difficult when presenting data in form of objects.
So lets say in the dictionary we have an array stored under the key "first array". I could like to name the expandable cell presenting that array with the name "first array". But the problem is that only the item itself is passed into the function below.
I could iterate through the dictionary and search for the object and then get its key but what if the array is in some far sub object or there are two identical arrays.

```
- (id)outlineView:(NSOutlineView *)outlineView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)theColumn byItem:(id)item
    {

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
         return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",item];
    }

    if ([item isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]]) {
         return ?
    }
    ...
    }
```

I hope somebody has some thoughts to my process or knows where I could look to get more help. Thanks a lot!